# bodyParse error suppression

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm currently using bodyParser with Express to accept JSON requests. Whenever I pass in an incorrectly formed JSON object it returns a nasty error via the endpoint and logs it to the console as well. The following is the error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parse (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
    at /Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:108:18
    at done (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:239:14)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:285:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Object.parse (native)
    at parse (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
    at /Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:108:18
    at done (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:239:14)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/ddibiase-mbp/Documents/Projects/theride_api/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:285:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:199:16)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:908:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I'm wondering how I can suppress the error or patch this completely. I've investigated the error but can't find any specific recommendations for patching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common to declare an [error handler](http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html) with Express:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  ...
  return res.sendStatus(500);
});
```

This will also catch errors thrown in middleware like `body-parser`.

Comment: @ddibiase did you add it as the last middleware of your app, as documented?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, take a look:

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send({
        errors: [
            'invalid_request'
        ]
    });
});

Comment: Sorry, nevermind it's working successfully. I messed something up :-p